# How to place a UIButton (UIButtonTypeRoundedRect)in a UIScrollView but make the button transparent and keep its functionality?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I need a transparent rounded rect button in a UIScrollView applied to 40 buttons.

thanks

Comment: It will cost you $99. are you kidding what type or question is this.. [read faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: made modification to question

Comment: I need a pony.  Ask a real question.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
UIButton *b = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
```

Use custom `UIButton` type for transparent `UIButton`

Answer (score 1):

If you want make it custom with out using the image you can do like this :

```
CALayer *layer = <your btn>.layer;
layer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
layer.borderColor = [[UIColor darkGrayColor] CGColor];
layer.cornerRadius = 7.0f;
layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have an IBOutlet to 'exampleButton' in your class, the following should work

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    self.expandButton.alphaValue = 0;
}
```

(I guess you could have an outlet for each of the 40 buttons, but I guess it would be cleaner to subclass the button and put something into the init about setting it's own alpha)